# Listengin to Form Submit - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have a form that i listen to whenever a user submits the form. There are two ways i do submit my form.

1. Form submit by clicking on the form submit
2. When user selects an **li**

When i click on the form button to submit, it is detected by the listener in **File1.js** But when user clicks on the li for the function `items_sold(event);` to execute, the form submits, but the listener doesn't execute.

Why could this be happening ?

**HTML**

```html
<form class="shop_form" id="shop_form" method="get">
  <input name="items" type="text" id="shop__items" />
  <ul class="list_of_items" id="list_of_items" onclick="items_sold(event);">
    <li>Nutella</li>
    <li>Sweet Jam</li>
  </ul>

  <button class="shop_btn" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

**File1.JS**

```js
document.getElementById('shop_form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  alert('Form Submitted')
})
```

**File2.Js**

```js
function items_sold(event) {
  $('#shop_form').submit()
}
```

Comment: Try `function items_sold(event) { $('#shop_form .shop_btn').trigger('click'); }` instead.

Comment: @CBroe , this is also works for me as well when invoke click on the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`submit()` function doesn't triggers a `submit` event, so any callback function registered to run on `submit` event won't execute.

From [MDN - HTMLFormElement.submit():](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)

> This method is similar, but not identical to, activating a form's
> submit `<button>`. When invoking this method directly, however:
>
> - No submit event is raised. In particular, the form's onsubmit event handler is not run.
> - Constraint validation is not triggered.

Instead of `submit()` function, use `requestSubmit()` function. It will raise the `submit` event.

For more details, see [HTMLFormElement.requestSubmit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit)

Alternatively, you could submit the form by invoking `.click()` function on the `button` element

```
document.querySelector('.shop_btn').click();
```

For details on `.click()` function, see [HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Comment: requestSubmit() doesn't submit my form any longer

Comment: Thank you. Invoking the click() on the button works fine.

Answer (score -1):

```js
// convert this code 
        <ul class="list_of_items" id="list_of_items" onclick="items_sold(this.form);">

// then change the method defiantion like
function items_sold(form){
    form.submit();
}

//hope will help
```